# Bind ItemsControl with ItemsSource to the array index

Tags: wpf, arrays, binding, indexing, itemscontrol

I want to bind an ItemsControl to an array of object, using ItemsSource and DataTemplate.
And I want to show the index of each item.
Like

Customer 1:

Name: xxxx

Age:888

Customer 2:

Name: yyy

Age: 7777

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add an Index property to you class ;-) Otherwise it can be done using a MultiValueConverter:

```
<Window x:Class="IndexSpike.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:IndexSpike"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Name="Root"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:GetIndex x:Key="GetIndexConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource
                                            GetIndexConverter}"
                                            StringFormat="Index: {0}">
                                <Binding Path="."/>
                                <Binding ElementName="Root" Path="Persons"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}'}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat='Age {0}'}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace IndexSpike
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            Persons=new ObservableCollection<Person>
                        {
                            new Person("Me",20),
                            new Person("You",30)
                        };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name,int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age=age;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetIndex:IMultiValueConverter
    {
        #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var persons = (ObservableCollection<Person>) values[1];
            var person = (Person) values[0];
            return persons.IndexOf(person);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442165/wpf-usercontrol-in-datatemplate-within-itemscontrol-how-to-bind-to-parent-of-it) I found an other way to declare the MultiBinding:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetIndexConverter}"
                                          StringFormat="Index: {0}">
     <Binding Path="."/>
     <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" 
                                  Path="DataContext.Persons"/>
</MultiBinding>
```