# WPF: Accessing two DataContexts in the same control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am using an MVVM approach, and I have an object from my ViewModel called `DatabasesSubFrame` which is `DataTemplate`d to show a `ListBox`. I want to display a `Button` below the `ListBox`, which binds to both the currently `SelectedItem`, and a property on the `DatabasesSubFrame` object which is being `DataTemplate`d.

I know how to refer to the currently selected item, by setting the `DataContext` on a shared ancestor with the `ListBox` and use `{Binding /}`. In this example the shared ancestor is a `StackPanel`. And if the `DataContext` wasn't explicitly set there I could easily bind to a property on the `DatabasesSubFrame` object by just doing `{Binding SomeProperty}`. However, if I do `{Binding SomeProperty}` within the explicitly set `DataContext`, it refers to the wrong `DataContext`.

How do I access the "original" `DataContext` here? I tried messing with RelativeSources and TemplatedParents but couldn't figure out how to fit them in.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:DatabasesSubFrame}">
  <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Databases}" >
     <ListBox Name="DbInfoBox" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Label Content="{Binding ShortName}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
     <!-- Problem: The Command and V:CreateCommandBinding.Command are set incorrectly here. How do I access OpenDbCommand from the top-level DataTemplate's DataContext? -->
     <Button Content="Open Database"
             CommandParameter="{Binding /}"
             Command="{Binding ???, Path=OpenDbCommand.Command}"
             V:CreateCommandBinding.Command="{Binding ???, Path=DataContext.OpenDbCommand}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: It looks like I can modify my data items to hold a reference to the parent viewmodel object, but that seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442165/wpf-usercontrol-in-datatemplate-within-itemscontrol-how-to-bind-to-parent-of-it) will help you to find the answer to yours. Another trick is to set the Name of the Window to something like "Root". You can then get at the window's original datacontext by using:

```
{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.MyViewModelsProperty}
```